# JS output message printed on a div tag in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, innerhtml

i am struggling with something pretty simple, i think. 
I have a form and when the user is picking their answers i suppose to appear a message inside the DIV tag.

my code sample is here:

```js
    function check(){
   //var display_answer = document.myform.answer.value;
    
    var q1 = document.myform.q1.value;
    var q2 = document.myform.q2.value;
    
    if(q1 == "a" && q2 == "a"){
   document.getElementById("div").innerHTML= "Green!";
    }
    if(q1 == "a" && q2 == "b"){
      document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Red!";
    }
    if(q1 == "b" && q2 == "a"){
      document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Yellow!";
    }
    if(q1 == "b" && q2 == "b"){
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Blue!";
    }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Food Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myform">
    Question 1: Question...?
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"> Answer A </br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"> Answer B </br></br>
    
    
    Question 2: Question...?
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a"> Answer A </br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b"> Answer B </br></br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()">
    </br>
    </br>
    </form>
    
    <p>
    Results:
    </p>
    </br>
    <div style="background-color:lightblue" id="div" name="answer">
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The truth is, i don't get any results. When the user picks a combination of the 2 given answers (one from each question) it gets the color result, printed on the DIV tag with the id=div.

Any ideas of what went wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: console.log() is your friend

Comment: seems to work fine to me when I add your code to a snipplet. Where is the code included in that HTML?

Comment: Your code works (well for question 2 it does), but your HTML has some invalid syntax `</br>` should just be `<br>` and `.innerHTML` is for getting/setting strings that contain HTML in them. When the strings don't, use `.textContent`.

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to help you with the "right" behavior because your code talks about "answer a" and "answer b" and responds with colors. We have no way of understanding what your logic is with regard to what it is supposed to show when the various combinations of buttons get chosen.

Comment: When you say "i don't get any results", what do you mean? In your check() logic, your conditionals only handle if values have been selected for both. If you haven't selected one of the groups of radio buttons, the value will be blank - but you're not checking for blank (for example: `if (q1 == "")`), so nothing happens.

Comment: Surprisingly, here on the "Run code snippet" works absolutely fine. But it's on my website that it doesn't :(    And yes the <br/> was a wrong syntax i meant to use </br> instead thx @Scott Marcus for the notice. You can also print Strings with innerHTML, i don't think i misuse this one.

Comment: I don't know if i mention i use this code into a page on Wordpress will make any difference to your comments, won't it?

Comment: @BrainWash Actually, you used `</br>`, which is invalid. `<br />` will work, but is really something called XHTML. The HTML is just `<br>` and that's what you should use. Also, `.innerHTML` will *work*, but it forces the browser to parse the string for HTML, which is a waste of resources when there is no HTML to parse. Additionally, `.innerHTML` opens up security holes in your application. In cases where there is no HTML (like in your case, where you are only using non-HTML strings), use `.textContent`, which does not parse the string for HTML and therefore is the right thing to do.

Comment: Above all, remember this, just because something seems to *work* in the world of web development, doesn't mean it's *right*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code snippet a little bit and this works. Basically, I added `method="post"` to the form. I changed the submit button type to `type="submit"`. Here is a good resource for [HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp). To prevent browser action, I change the onclick operation for the submit button `onclick="check(); return false;"`. Here is a good resource for that: [Browser Default Actions](https://javascript.info/default-browser-action)

I also changed the id of your div message to `id="resultMessage"`. You usually want a unique id. For the JavaScript snippet, i just made one variable to reference the div element and use that variable in the if statements.

And yes, `console.log()` is your best friend!

```js
function check() {
  var q1 = document.myform.q1.value;
  var q2 = document.myform.q2.value;
  
  var divResult = document.getElementById("resultMessage");

  if (q1 == "a" && q2 == "a") {
    divResult.innerHTML = "Green!";
  }
  if (q1 == "a" && q2 == "b") {
    divResult.innerHTML = "Red!";
  }
  if (q1 == "b" && q2 == "a") {
    divResult.innerHTML = "Yellow!";
  }
  if (q1 == "b" && q2 == "b") {
    divResult.innerHTML = "Blue!";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Food Quiz</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="myform" method="post">
      <label for="q1">Question 1: Question...?</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"> Answer A </br>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"> Answer B </br>
      </br>


      <label for="q2">Question 2: Question...?</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a"> Answer A </br>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b"> Answer B </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="check(); return false;">
      </br>
      </br>
    </form>

    <p>
      Results:
    </p>
    </br>
    <div style="background-color:lightblue" id="resultMessage" name="answer">
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx @John Bullington for his useful help and the guide he gave me on the method forms (i completely forgot about). console.log() is indeed the most useful tool!  Also i wanna give credits to Scott Marcus for his help too. And everyone else who pointed out my faults! I managed to run this one right. As Wordpress is a bit tricky with its JS scripts on its body content. I used the HTML code from above and kept the JS into an external file and called it on the page. And guess what, it worked that way. thx again